# Angularjs: How to build a controller reuseable?

Tags: angularjs, inheritance, controller

I have an application with some controllers that have the same functions as: InitMenu, GetData, Search, Paging, ..

How can I build a generic controller with the main functions: InitMenu, GetData, Search, Paging, .. without having to write in each specific controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

share all the common logic inside a service and inject it inside your controllers.

```
.service('CommonData, function(){
   this.getData = function(){
   }
   this.InitMenu= function(){
   }
   this.search= function(){
   } 
})
```

otherwise you can make a parent controller and all the child controllers will prototype inherit from the parent scope.

```
.controller('ParentCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.myObj = {};
  $scope.parentMethod = function(){
    return myObj;
  }
})

.controller('ChildCtrl', function($scope){
 var stuff = $scope.parentMethod(); 
//you can access the parent method in the child template as well
})

<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    <div ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
      {{parentMethod()}}
      //if you use controllAs syntax change it to {{parentCtrlName.parentMethod()}}
    </div>
</div>
```

if you use `controllerAs` syntax you can access the parent `$scope` by specifyng the controller name as a scope field in the child controller. e.g `$scope.parentCtrlName.parentMethod()` and `parentCtrlname.parentMethod()` in the child template.

Comment: Thanks @Karim, but my opinion is build a Controller that can be inherited by other controllers (it look like inheritance in .NET). Any way to make this?

Comment: yes you can make a parent controller , and all the children controllers will prototype inherit all the methods from the parent, i'll fix my answer :)

Comment: you're welcome, if the answer helped you please mark it as correct. :)